# Effectiveness of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, x86-64, compiler-optimization, unique-ptr

I liked `std::unique_ptr` the moment I saw it back in c++11, but I questioned it's effectiveness for quite a while.  (see link below for link to live code) :

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> get();
extern std::unique_ptr<int> val;

void foo()
{
    val = get();
}
```

This gave me 16 instructions on last clang with `-O3`. But what is more interesting is that it generated two calls to `delete`, even though the second one will never be called.

Than I tried to do it like this:

```
void foo()
{
    auto ptr = get().release();
    val.reset(ptr);
}
```

And suddenly it's just 11 instructions. Then I went deeper and hacked unique_ptr move ctor. Originally it is implemented as `reset(__u.release());`. I basically just reordered it as follows:

```
auto& ptr =  _M_ptr();
if (ptr)
    _M_deleter()(ptr);
ptr = __u.release();
```

Aaand.... 11 instructions as in hand-managed version. It is slightly different but seems ok.

I saved my experiments [here](https://godbolt.org/z/saK8nfjh5).

Can someone point out is that it's I'm missing something or it's actually somehow intended?

Comment: do you mean "efficiency" or really "effectiveness" ?

Comment: Feeling a bit simple here... but `std::unique_ptr<int> get();` is a function to return a unique int pointer... but don't we need a function?  Or does it mean something else?

Comment: It's easy to make programs run much faster if you stop caring if they're right.

Comment: I think that release() sets the pointer to 0, and the code checks if that pointer is 0 before the second delete, which the compiler would normally optimize, but there is a call to operator delete in the middle, and it has difficulties proving that that call doesn't make the pointer non-0 again.

Comment: Self move-assignment behaves differently, doesn't it?

Comment: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/08/20/rule-of-zero-pitfall/

Comment: Stack overflow is for specific questions.   "Am I missing anything?" is not a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of operations for move-assignment *must* be:

1. Make a copy of the managed source pointer, and null it in the source object.
2. If the destination managed pointer is not null, delete it.
3. Set the destination managed pointer in the destination object.

Note that this logic happily results in a no-op for self-move-assignment.

The reason the logic must be this way is the source may be owned by the destination.

Imagine:

```
struct list { std::unique_ptr<list> next; };
std::unique_ptr<list> head;
// ...
if (head) head = std::move(head->next);
```

This will not behave correctly if `head->next`'s managed pointer isn't nulled before deleting the old object managed by `head`.

In code, move assignment therefore is just:

```
reset(source.release())
```

Your last snippet obviously fails to null the source before deletion, and is thus not a viable implementation for move assignment:

```
auto& ptr =  _M_ptr();
if (ptr)
    _M_deleter()(ptr);
ptr = __u.release();
```

That leaves your question about why

```
val = get();
```

is different than

```
auto ptr = get().release();
val.reset(ptr);
```

The difference is in the implicit `unique_ptr<int>` returned from `get()`. In the first version, it is destroyed after both the `release` and `reset`. In the second version it is destroyed after `release` but before `reset`. In both cases, it is nulled by the time it is destroyed, and there need not be a delete. But the compiler must be unable to propagate the knowledge that this pointer was nulled across the `reset`.